# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de fuente de la barra de navegación cuando hace scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

Tengo una navbar transparente con texto blanco, cuando hago scroll down a la pagina me gustaría que el texto cambiara a color negro. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Adjunto mi  código JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#header').addClass('header-scrolled');
            $('#topbar').addClass('topbar-scrolled');
        } else {
            $('#header').removeClass('header-scrolled');
            $('#topbar').removeClass('topbar-scrolled');
        }
    });
```

Adjunto mi código CSS:

Trate de colocar un color: black desde CSS pero no me funciono

```
#header {
    background: rgba(53, 50, 50, 0);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index: 997;
    padding: 15px 0;
    top: 30px;
}

#header.header-scrolled {
    top: 0;
    /*  background: linear-gradient(#616168dc, black);*/
    background: linear-gradient(#b4b4b8c2, rgb(255, 255, 255));
    color: black;
}
```

Adjunto mi código HTML:

```
<header id="header" class="fixed-top ">
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">

            

            <a href="index.html" class="logo mr-auto scrollto"><img src="assets/img/logoqfs.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>

            <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="iso45001-2018.html">HOLA</a></li>                                                  
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Proceso de Certificación</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Hola @Mayra, ¿podrías proporcionar el código HTML asociado a la pregunta?

Comment: si claro, una discula

Comment: Ya lo he añadido, espero me pueda auxiliar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que tu problema es porque estás estableciendo el color negro a todo el #header. Para el caso de los links vas a tener que agregar el siguiente código CSS:

```
#header.header-scrolled a {
    color: black;
}
```

Esto se llama "especificidad" e indica cómo los navegadores calculan las propiedades CSS.

Comment: Tienes razón, me olvide del detalle de ser especifica. Ya lo he probado y me funciono perfectamente, muchísimas gracias ^_^